# Input-view navigation-mode does not read list

Tags: bixby

I've tried implementing an input-view with navigation-mode so that the user can verbally select an option. The goal is to have my capsule completely usable without physical interaction.

The issue is that I tried to follow the example from the Developer Center, but it doesn't seem to work properly. https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/enhancing-UX.list-navigation

```
input-view {
  match: SpaceResort (result)
  message ("Which space resort would you like?")
  render {
    if (size(result) > 1) {
      selection-of (result) {
        navigation-mode {
          read-one {
            list-summary ("I found #{size(result)} resorts.")
            page-content {
              underflow-statement (This is the first resort.)
              item-selection-question (Do you want to book this resort?)
              overflow-statement (Those are all the resorts that meet your search.)
              overflow-question (What would you like to do?)
            }
          }
        }
        has-details (true)
        select-button-text ("Book")
        where-each (item) {
          layout-macro (space-resort-summary) {
            param (spaceResort) {
              expression (item)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On my capsule, it would repeat the 'item-selection-question', 'list-summary', or the message template twice, and it will not read out loud the list of items.

Comment: While digging a little more into this issue, I just want to first comment that the "repeat twice message" is a separate issue and confirmed bug. The fix is on the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online DOC example is not very clear.

You need to add child-key `spoken-summary` in `where-each (item)`. Please check more [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/input-view.render.selection-of.where-each.spoken-summary)

And in IDE testing, you need enable the "hands free" mode button. 
[image]

Currently on-device testing this feature is not enabled, yet.

Again, the repeat twice message is a bug, and will be fixed soon.